# How did this Order of the Odd Fellows health insurance plan work in this 1845 newspaper article?

Tags: 19th-century, finance, business-history, health, freemasonry

The newspaper in question comes from the Library of Congress's Chronicling America collection, an incredible resource if you are unaware of it. It is a massive online collection of old newspapers. This paper is the [second page of the 18 September 1845 issue of the Indiana State Sentinel](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015677/1845-09-18/ed-1/seq-2/). The article in question can be found at the top of the column that is second from the right, titled "Odd Fellowship". The article is quoting an "article", it says, though it seems more like an advertisement, from the Savannah Georgian, about the Order of Odd Fellowship.

I am having trouble parsing out what is meant, and I am hoping someone could help. So, the quoted article begins by lauding the benefits of the "principle of Association", and concludes "that the weakness incident to nature and the accidents of fortune, can only be guarded against by a system of mtual dependence and support." It then introduces "Odd Fellowship" as a "Mutual health-insurance company". The fees are $20 to get into the lodge ($750.93 today) with the annual fee being $7.50 ($281.60 today). The benefits are $5 a week ($187.73 today) while out of work. With an additional $10 ($375.47) up-front, and additional $4 ($150.19) a year, they received benefits at the next tier. So, $30 ($1,126.40) up-front and $11.50 ($431.79) a year, he would get $8 ($300.37) a week while incapacitated.

But, when the article sums up the original and additional costs, my first question arises. It says,

> "The expense attending his attainment of the highest degree is thirty dollars. The annual contribution is eleven dollars and a half, less than the interest upon one hundred and fifty dollars..."

First Question: Where did this interest on 150 dollars come from? Who has this 150 dollars? Does the lodge have this $150? And, so, if the Lodge gets a good enough interest rate, then the $11.50 is waived?

Then, continuing where we left off:

> "...and should misfortune overtake him, and a wasting disease lay upon him its afflicting hand, he receives, not as charity, but a debt due to him from his Lodge, the sum of four hundred and sixteen dollars per annum, or at that rate for any less period of time being the interest upon an investment of five thousand two hundred dollars at eight percent"

I'm not sure what this is saying, so my second question is what does this mean? Does this mean if the person is incapacitated permanently, they receive the $416? But, this doesn't seem to suggest a death benefit, because it says "per annum", and it never mentions survivors. Whether or not this is a death benefit takes on more meaning later. And, where does the 8% interest on $5,200 come from?

Continuing on to the next paragraph, it says,

> "In a life insurance, taking the age of thirty, which is under the mean age, in all the schemes to insure for life in Georgia, for the sum of thousand dollars, there is required an annual payment of one hundred and fifty-seven dollars and a half, to insure one’s health for the annual interest on five thousand two hundred dollars, requires after the original payment of thirty dollars, but the sum of eleven dollars and a half yearly, with the difference in favor of the latter, that a premium on a life insurance policy increases with the age of the applicant -- in Odd Fellowship there is no such distinction, except in some few Lodges an increased charge of perhaps some five dollars is made in the initiatory payment."

This confuses me and elucidates the issue, so my third question regards this. So, this makes me think that life insurance policies were initially set up in such a way that when you got insured for $10,000, the amount of benefit you received was the annual interest paid on $10,000 at a fixed-rate. But, I imagine the interest does not compound, so it's just that rate at that amount forever? 8% of 5200 is $416, so in 12 and a half years, when the interest starts going above $5,200, does the insured get more?

So, I think I understand better now that I've written everything out, but I am not sure, and I think this could be interesting, so I will leave it in, but anyone please feel free to edit what they deem unnecessary. So, I think the $416 from the second question is in fact a death benefit, and the $416 received is for each year paid into the program. So, $416*number of years paid in. So, my only question remaining is that I am still unsure as to what the whole "The annual contribution is elven dollars and a half, less than the interest upon one hundred and fifty dollars." What does this mean?

Anyways, thanks for any clarity you could provide on the final question.

Comment: 1st question - 150 is simply a comparison, not relevant. 2, "416/annum" means yearly. I don't understand the rest of your questions.

Comment: @MCW So, when it says "The annual contribution is elven dollars and a half, less than the interest upon one hundred and fifty dollars," the interest on $150 is just an arbitrarily "small" number pointing out that the interest on a "meager" savings account of $150 (>$5,500 today) would cover the annual costs? Is that what they are getting at? That is the only question I have left about the article.

Comment: Current thesis is that the dues to the lodge pay the interest on the policy at each tier. This is clearest if you break down the dues at the level of the $5000 policy.  At a lower tier, the sum of the costs is $168, which is near the $150.  Interesting (pun intended) question, and I hope the community will be smarter than I.

Comment: Your comparisons of the value of money are uncited, and don't mention the method of comparison (CPI would be a bad choice btw).  If you're having trouble parsing mid 19th century financial advice aimed at skilled workers; or having difficulty placing the Odd Fellows in labour history, I'd suggest more time in JSTOR before you publish your original research.  Workers self-insurance should be heavily documented, so your original contributions will shine out against the past works.

Comment: Still using JSTOR, thanks for the recommendation. Found a couple things, nothing so far helpful. As for the History of the Odd Fellows, I find nothing specific, such as how long they were offering this insurance, or what the specific costs and benefits of early membership were. Only vague care in times of need type stuff. Still looking, though. I've never published before.I thought I would try to get published in a more popular magazine or something, never thought of doing it academically. I just know I stumbled onto something and I don't want to be the only one to know. Driving me crazy.

Comment: @SamuelRussell also, I used this website to compare money https://www.officialdata.org/us/inflation/1846  I have no idea where their data comes from. I never intended to publish these numbers. Thank you for the heads on different types of inflation comparison. Which do you recommend? And, I don't see anywhere on there where it says how they determined their numbers. I would welcome your analysis on it.

Comment: Measuringworth.com should explain the basic post 1789 issues with comparisons: wages, consumption, capital and states consider money over time differently.

Comment: Whoa. Thank you, much. I never realized there was such a range.

Comment: officialdata.org in that page uses CPI data.  CPI data is determined by a set of "consumption items" specified by the organ (usually a state) as "consumable for the average worker."  Australia's Bureau of Statistics infamously has been forced to **exclude** housing from the CPI figures.  Housing is, remarkably, over one half of an Australian workers' post tax income.  Other comparisons than CPI use different principles, based largely on capital, or proportion of social economy.  Measuring in capital tells you if workers have lost money.  Measuring societies tells you how much a war costs.